# Vs code not suggesting Spatie\YamlFrontMatter\YamlFrontMatter

Tags: php, laravel, yaml

Spatie\YamlFrontMatter\YamlFrontMatter is not being suggest by vs code

I followed the steps as given on this page
https://github.com/spatie/yaml-front-matter

Then I manually typed the code and it worked but showing warnings.

Attaching the screenshots.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I am using

```
$ php artisan -v
Laravel Framework 9.52.4
```

and I am learning from Laravel framework 8 from
https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-8-from-scratch/

Comment: Sometimes you need to restart the editor to re-index the vendor files.
Restart VS Code and check it again.

Comment: Have you added your package to the composer.json and then ran `composer update`?

Comment: Thank you Amigos. I re-installed the package using command
$ composer require spatie/yaml-front-matter
and manually copied this line of code
use Spatie\YamlFrontMatter\YamlFrontMatter;
and restarted my VS code.
And it worked.!!!!
For more detail check the link below. Gracias
https://github.com/spatie/yaml-front-matter